# shiny error: cannot coerce class ‘c("reactiveExpr", "reactive", "function")’ to a data.frame

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing a shiny app that takes two separate datasets as input, 'd' and 'r':

```
cats <- c(1,2,3,'R','V')
ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput('d','Deine Daten'),
  fileInput('r','Rote Liste'),
  checkboxGroupInput('kate', 'Zu beachtender RL Kategorien', cats),
  textInput('rl_de', 'Spalte mit RL DE'),
  textInput('rl_rg', 'Spalte mit regionaler RL'),
  textInput('rl_gw', 'Spalte mit gewüschter RL'),
  textInput('ort', 'Spalte mit Ortsnamen'),
  textInput('art', 'Spalte mit Artsnamen'),
  downloadButton('analyse','Speichern'),
  dataTableOutput("dynamic")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data_d <- reactive({
    req(input$d)
    
    ext <- tools::file_ext(input$d$name)
    return.data_d <- switch(ext,
                            csv = vroom::vroom(input$d$datapath, delim = ";"),
                            validate("Invalide Datei; Bitte .csv Datei laden")
    )
    return.data_d <- rote_liste(data_d, data_r(), rl_de(), rl_sh(), ortname(),
                                artname(), kate(), rl_gw())
    return.data_d
  })
  
  data_r <- reactive({
    req(input$r)
    ext <- tools::file_ext(input$r$name)
    return.data <- switch(ext,
                          csv = vroom::vroom(input$r$datapath, delim = ";"),
                          validate("Invalide Datei; Bitte .csv Datei laden")
    )
    return.data_r
  })
  
  rl_de <- reactive(input$rl_de)
  rl_rg <- reactive(input$rl_rg)
  rl_gw <- reactive(input$rl_gw)
  ortname <- reactive(input$ort)
  artname <- reactive(input$art)
  kate <- reactive(input$kate)
  
  output$analyse <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      'rl_daten.csv'
    },
    content = function(file) {
      vroom::vroom_write(data_d(), file, delim = ";")
    }
  )
  output$dynamic <- renderDataTable(data_d(), options = list(pageLength = 5))
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, when running the app and loading the data I get this error: 'cannot coerce class ‘c("reactiveExpr", "reactive", "function")’ to a data.frame'
I have seen that in other similar threads the problem was adding a () to reactive variables, but that doesn't seem to be the exact same problem here, and I can't find an alternative solution.

The functions I the app is running with take data sets, the labeling of columns and some selected values. They don't seem to be the problem here:

```
rote_liste <- function(data, gef, RL_DE, RL_SH, Ort, Art, cats, RL) {
  data1 <- as_tibble(data) %>%
    select(c(.data[[Ort]],.data[[Art]])) %>%
    left_join(gef, by = Art) %>%
    filter(.data[[RL_DE]] %in%  cats | .data[[RL_DE]] %in% cats)
  data1 <- sprechblasen(data1, cats, RL, Ort, Art)
  return(data1)
}

sprechblasen <- function(data, cats, RL, Ort, Art) {
  tables <- vector(mode = 'list', length = length(cats))
  for (i in 1:length(cats)) {
    dat <- data %>%
      filter(.data[[RL]] == cats[i]) %>%
      select(c(.data[[Ort]],.data[[Art]],.data[[RL]])) %>%
      group_by(.data[[Ort]]) %>%
      summarise (ArtenListe = paste(unique(.data[[Art]]), collapse = ", ")) %>%
      mutate (Status = cats[i])
    tables[[i]] <- dat
  }
  return(data.table::rbindlist(tables))
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are using `data_d` inside the definition of `data_d <-` that is confusing. Before defining `data_d` as reactive, does a different `data_d` object exist? It is hard to help you without an reproducible example.

Comment: This error is usually caused when you forget to add `()` when using a reactive object. However, in your case you seem to recursively depend on `data_d`, and that's a mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Solved the issue :D

Comment: @Tuck You can post your own answer to the question below to mark it as answered, or you can just delete your question.